# Teechart Event List

Tags: activex, teechart

Can Anyone let me know what all events are supported by Teechart and also can we detect the data or property edited by user in the editing windows.

Thanks
Akshay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can Anyone let me know what all events are supported by Teechart

Here you have the list of events that are defined in TeeChart ActiveX:

```
procedure OnAfterDraw; dispid 1;
procedure OnBeforeDrawSeries; dispid 29;
procedure OnBeforeDrawAxes; dispid 30;
procedure OnClick; dispid 3;
procedure OnClickAxis(Axis: Integer; Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer;
                      Y: Integer); dispid 4;
procedure OnClickBackground(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 5;
procedure OnClickLegend(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 6;
procedure OnClickSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; Button: EMouseButton;
                        Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 7;
procedure OnDblClick; dispid 8;
procedure OnDragDrop(X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 9;
procedure OnDragOver(X: Integer; Y: Integer; State: EDragState; var Accept: WordBool); dispid 10;
procedure OnEndDrag(X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 11;
procedure OnEnter; dispid 12;
procedure OnExit; dispid 13;
procedure OnGetAxisLabel(Axis: Integer; SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer;
                         var LabelText: WideString); dispid 14;
procedure OnGetLegendRect(var Left: Integer; var Top: Integer; var Right: Integer;
                          var Bottom: Integer); dispid 16;
procedure OnGetNextAxisLabel(Axis: Integer; LabelIndex: Integer; var LabelValue: Double;
                             var MoreLabels: WordBool); dispid 18;
procedure OnMouseDown(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 19;
procedure OnMouseMove(Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 20;
procedure OnMouseUp(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 21;
procedure OnPageChange; dispid 22;
procedure OnResize; dispid 23;
procedure OnScroll; dispid 24;
procedure OnStartDrag; dispid 25;
procedure OnUndoZoom; dispid 26;
procedure OnZoom; dispid 27;
procedure OnAllowScroll(Axis: EAxisType; var AMin: Double; var AMax: Double;
                        var AllowScroll: WordBool); dispid 2;
procedure OnGetLegendPos(ItemIndex: Integer; var X: Integer; var Y: Integer; var XColor: Integer); dispid 15;
procedure OnGetLegendText(LegendStyle: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; var LegendText: WideString); dispid 17;
procedure OnDatabaseRecord(SeriesIndex: Integer; Index: Integer; var StopRetrieve: WordBool); dispid 28;
procedure OnTimer; dispid 31;
procedure OnGetSeriesMark(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; var MarkText: WideString); dispid 32;
procedure OnGetSeriesPointerStyle(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer;
                                  var AStyle: EPointerStyle); dispid 33;
procedure OnGetSeriesContourLevel(SeriesIndex: Integer; LevelIndex: Integer;
                                  var LevelValue: Double; var LevelColor: OLE_COLOR); dispid 34;
procedure OnBeforeDrawChart; dispid 39;
procedure OnSeriesBeforeDrawValues(SeriesIndex: Integer); dispid 36;
procedure OnSeriesAfterDrawValues(SeriesIndex: Integer); dispid 35;
procedure OnMarkTipToolGetText(Tool: Integer; var Text: WideString); dispid 37;
procedure OnCursorToolChange(Tool: Integer; X: Integer; Y: Integer; XVal: Double; YVal: Double;
                             Series: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer); dispid 40;
procedure OnDrawLineToolLineDrag; dispid 41;
procedure OnDrawLineToolNewLine; dispid 42;
procedure OnDrawLineToolDraggedLine; dispid 43;
procedure OnDrawLineToolSelectLine; dispid 44;
procedure OnCalendarSeriesChange(Series: Integer; Value: Double); dispid 38;
procedure OnSeriesBeforeAdd(SeriesIndex: Integer; var MoreValues: WordBool); dispid 45;
function OnMouseEnterSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer): HResult; dispid 201;
function OnMouseLeaveSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer): HResult; dispid 202;
procedure OnSeriesContourBeforeDrawLevel(SeriesIndex: Integer; LevelIndex: Integer); dispid 203;
function OnSeriesAnimationToolStep(Tool: Integer; Step: Integer): HResult; dispid 204;
function OnGanttToolDragBar(Tool: Integer; GanttBar: Integer): HResult; dispid 205;
function OnGanttToolResizeBar(Tool: Integer; GanttBar: Integer; BarPart: EGanttToolPartBar): HResult; dispid 206;
function OnFunctionCalculate(SeriesIndex: Integer; X: Double; var Y: Double): HResult; dispid 207;
function OnCompressFunctionGetDate(FunctionSeriesIndex: Integer; SourceSeriesIndex: Integer;
                                   ValueIndex: Integer; var D: TDateTime): HResult; dispid 208;
function OnGaugeChange(SeriesIndex: Integer): HResult; dispid 209;
function OnNearestToolChange: HResult; dispid 210;
function OnBeforePrint: HResult; dispid 211;
function OnKeyDown(KeyCode: Integer; Shift: EShiftState): HResult; dispid 212;
function OnKeyUp(KeyCode: Integer; Shift: EShiftState): HResult; dispid 213;
function OnLegendScrollBarToolScrolled: HResult; dispid 214;
function OnSurfaceNearestToolSelectCell: HResult; dispid 215;
procedure OnDrawAxisLabel(Axis: Integer; X: Integer; Y: Integer; var LabelText: WideString); dispid 216;
procedure OnLegendDrawSymbol(Series: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; Left: Integer; Top: Integer;
                             Right: Integer; Bottom: Integer); dispid 217;
procedure OnColorBandToolClick(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 218;
function OnRotateToolRotate: HResult; dispid 219;
procedure OnColorLineToolBeginDragLine; dispid 220;
procedure OnColorLineToolDragLine; dispid 221;
procedure OnColorLineToolEndDragLine; dispid 222;
procedure OnDragPointToolDragPoint(Index: Integer); dispid 223;
procedure OnDrawLineToolSelecting(Index: Integer; AllowSelect: WordBool); dispid 224;
function OnSelectorToolDragged: HResult; dispid 225;
function OnSelectorToolDragging: HResult; dispid 226;
function OnSelectorToolResized: HResult; dispid 227;
function OnSelectorToolResizing: HResult; dispid 228;
function OnSelectorToolSelected: HResult; dispid 229;
procedure OnAnnotationToolClick(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 230;
function OnRectangleToolDragging: HResult; dispid 231;
function OnRectangleToolResizing: HResult; dispid 232;
procedure OnRectangleToolClick(Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 233;
procedure OnSeriesAfterAdd(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer); dispid 234;
procedure OnGetSeriesBarStyle(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; var BarStyle: EBarStyle); dispid 235;
function OnVideoToolNewFrame: HResult; dispid 236;
function OnVideoToolStart: HResult; dispid 237;
function OnVideoToolStop: HResult; dispid 238;
function OnVideoPlayerToolFrame: HResult; dispid 239;
function OnOpenGLInit: HResult; dispid 240;
function OnOpenGLRepaint: HResult; dispid 241;
procedure OnCursorToolSnapChange(Tool: Integer; X: Integer; Y: Integer; XVal: Double;
                                 YVal: Double; Series: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer); dispid 242;
procedure OnDragMarksToolDraggedMark(Index: Integer; Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState;
                                     X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 243;
procedure OnDragMarksToolDraggingMark(Index: Integer; Button: EMouseButton; Shift: EShiftState;
                                      X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 244;
function OnRectangleToolDragged: HResult; dispid 245;
function OnRectangleToolResized: HResult; dispid 246;
function OnMarkTipToolCancelHint: HResult; dispid 247;
procedure OnSeriesClickPointer(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; X: Integer; Y: Integer); dispid 248;
procedure OnSeriesClickPointer3D(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer; X: Integer;
                                 Y: Integer); dispid 249;
function OnFaderToolStop: HResult; dispid 250;
function OnAxisArrowToolClick(ToolIndex: Integer; AtStart: WordBool): HResult; dispid 251;
function OnColorBandToolResized: HResult; dispid 252;
procedure OnAddSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer); dispid 253;
procedure OnRemoveSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer); dispid 254;
function OnLegendScrollBarToolChangeSize: HResult; dispid 255;
procedure OnLegendScrollBarToolSetPosition(Value: Integer); dispid 256;
procedure OnImageSeriesGetImage(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer;
                                var Picture: ITeePicture); dispid 257;
procedure OnGetSeriesCircleLabel(SeriesIndex: Integer; Angle: Double; Index: Integer;
                                 var Text: WideString); dispid 258;
procedure OnTagCloudSeriesDrawTag(SeriesIndex: Integer; ValueIndex: Integer); dispid 259;
procedure OnSurfaceSeriesGetYValue(SeriesIndex: Integer; X: Integer; Z: Integer; var Y: Double); dispid 260;
procedure OnDataTableToolFilterSeries(SeriesIndex: Integer; var Accept: WordBool); dispid 261;
function OnSubChartToolDragged: HResult; dispid 262;
function OnSubChartToolDragging: HResult; dispid 263;
function OnSubChartToolResized: HResult; dispid 264;
function OnSubChartToolResizing: HResult; dispid 265;
function OnDragPointToolStartDrag(index: Integer; start: WordBool): HResult; dispid 266;
```

Note TeeChart ActiveX is a wrapper from TeeChart VCL version.

> can we detect the data or property edited by user in the editing
>   windows

Not in general. Of course you can save the status of a property before opening the editor and compare it later.

On the other hand, note the TeeChart editor was thought to help the developers to design their charts minimizing the code writting, but it hasn't been thought for the end users. It has so many options that makes it difficult to predict and handle all the possibilities  a user may set, some of them non necessarily coherent.